# .NET Web Form ERROR: net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Tags: .net, http, iis, .net-4.8

In a old project a page throws this issue but not always sometimes it is opening. So im really confused.

Comment: You can find the solution in following topic:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706998/how-to-fix-err-invalid-chunked-encoding-error>

Comment: It is impossible to analyze and reproduce your problem based on these error messages alone, what is your project? does the problem occur after deploying to iis? please post more details information about your requirement.